# How to remove 2gp package password using SFDX?

Tags: managed-package, isv, unlocked-package, 2gp

Can we able to remove the published package password or remove it?

We have already submitted the package now we need to remove the password how to do it using sfdx.

> `sfdx force:package:version:update -p 04t... -e "Updated Desc" -x`
>
> ERROR running force:package:version:update:  Unexpected argument: -x
> See more help with --help

Not sure what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `-x` parameter is only for `force:package:version:create`. You should be able to simply specify `-k` with nothing after it to set a null installation key.

Comment: Sorry we are getting error when we try `-k`

`ERROR running force:package:version:update:  Flag --installationkey expects a value`

Comment: @Ragul That's a bummer. The docs were unclear on that exactly, but I figured it was worth a shot. Worst case scenario, you might just need to upload a new version. Installation keys are per-version, not per-package.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to remove the password once the version is created.

Maybe in the future, they can bring this feature.

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution:** Use an empty string

```
sfdx package version update --package "YOUR PACKAGE@1.0.0-1" --installation-key ""
```

Note: Package is not promoted when I did the test